# Modifying the edit Button in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I want to add the 'target="_blank"' parameter to the edit Button in my wiki, so edit pages will open up in a new window.

I think the simplest way to do this is to edit the specific file which creates this element, but as i am not familiar with the architecture of mediawiki i wasnt able to find this one yet.
Does anybody know where to find this part of code?

Comment: Hmm someone is participating in GCI this year?

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against patching the MediaWiki core - and also, in this case it's kind of hard. Assuming you're using a standard skin, SkinTemplate.php makes the links as property arrays (look for `$content_navigation['views']['edit']`), and then the skin (VectorTemplate.php, for example) actually outputs them as HTML. You will have to patch the individual skin - in VectorTemplate.php, you can look for "p-views" and add an `if ( $key === '$key' )` to add your target.

**Alternatively**, and probably a bit better, you can hack the [LinkTarget extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LinkTarget) so that it can accept IDs as well as classes, and then you could use that to target the specific "edit" link ('#ca-edit'). If you contribute the code back, you won't even have to maintain a fork, unlike the first option.

And third, you can just go the easy route, and use Javascript - just edit `MediaWiki:Common.js` on the wiki, and add something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $( '#ca-edit a' ).attr( 'target', '_blank' );
}
```